# We would like to update the Huawei developer name

Tags: appgallery-connect

I want to change my developer name in Huawei App Gallery. Could you please provide me step by step process?

Comment: Please read [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/14945696).and also read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer.

If  you want to update developer name ,

1. Please **sign in** to the **HUAWEI Developers console**,
2. Go to **Developer center** > **Settings** > **My profile**, set Developer name, and click Submit. Please refer the below images:

[image]

[image]

Once applied for the renaming permission, you have to wait for **1 to 2 working days**
to complete the review process.

For more information, please refer to instructions in https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/nickname-settings.